# Merging and adding dictionary values in comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following three dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'python':15, 'java':2,'c#':3}
d2 = {'go':30,'c#':4, 'java':10,}
d3 = {'python':2,'ruby':7}
```

I have used the following code to merge and sum all values of the same keys.

```
d={}
for mydict in d1,d2,d3:
    for key in mydict:
        d[key] = d.get(key,0) + mydict[key]
print(d)
```

But I am not able to change this code into a comprehension.

I have already done it using collection.Counter and Itertools.chain() method.

Comment: Why does it need to be in a comprehension?

Comment: @roganjosh  I want to try it that way. Looks cleaner

Comment: I'd argue that it doesn't. Your code reads fine as it is to me (though you could make it more general to handle more than 3 dicts)

Comment: @roganjosh  Please show how could I make it more general.

Comment: How does your Counter+chain solution look like?

Comment: @Heap Overflow Not Counter +chain,  one solution use Counter, one solution use DefaultDict and chain

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {}
d = {key: di[key] + d.get(key, 0) for di in (d1, d2, d3) for key in di}
```

Output:

```
{'python': 2, 'java': 10, 'c#': 4, 'go': 30, 'ruby': 7}
```

What we do is iterate over each key in each dict and add the corresponding key, value pair.

Comment: I want the values to add up like python:17

Comment: @John understand, will fix

Answer (score 0):

One way using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

sum([Counter(d) for d in [d1, d2, d3]], Counter())
```

Output:

```
Counter({'python': 17, 'java': 12, 'c#': 7, 'go': 30, 'ruby': 7})
```

Comment: yes I have already tried it using Counter and Chain method. But couldn't convert it to comprehension

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that the solution is **not based on comprehension** but I think it is more clear and direct.

```
from typing import List
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dicts(dicts: List[dict]):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for d in dicts:
        for k,v in d.items():
            result[k] += v
    return result


d1 = {'python':15, 'java':2,'c#':3}
d2 = {'go':30,'c#':4, 'java':10,}
d3 = {'python':2,'ruby':7}

final_dict = merge_dicts([d1,d2,d3])
print(final_dict)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'python': 17, 'java': 12, 'c#': 7, 'go': 30, 'ruby': 7})
```